# How can I remove the “connecting to networked drive” popup when waking from sleep in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, nas

Every time I wake my laptop up, I get the “connecting to networked drives” popup. There has got to be a way to turn off this notification but have been unable to find a way.

I’m using a Western Digital “My Book Live” networked drive for reference.

Here is a screenshot of the pop up:

[image]

Comment: Anyone else with suggestions?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to following:

- Go to “System Preferences” > “Users & Groups.”
- Select your user account from the list on the left and click on “Login Items.”
- You should have “WD My Book Live” on this list, click on the “Hide” box.

This should make it mount quietly in the background. Reboot and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  

I did not install any software for the networked drive so the "WD My Book Live" doesn't exist under login items.

Unrelated to this issue, I ended up reformatting my computer yesterday and the popup still exists without installing anything.